# Evaluating a multiple Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, taylor-expansion, real-numbers

Consider the following function defined by a definite integral:
$$
F = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} G(z,h) \, \mathrm{d} t \, , 
$$ 
where $z$ and $h$ are positive real numbers (lengths).
Moreover, $h=L+A \sin ( t)$ where $L$ and $A$ are two positive reals.

> In the problem of interest,  $A \ll L \ll z$.

I was wondering whether there exist a way to expand the function $F$ in a sort of multiple Taylor series and express it at leading order.
Take for example:
$$
G (z,h) = \frac{h^4+h^3z+h^2z^2+hz^3+z^4}{\left( h^2+hz+z^2 \right)^{5/2}} \, .
$$

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

harhel

Comment: What is preventing you from a (multivariate) Taylor expansion? The way I understand it, there are 3 independt variables, $a,z,t$, you could re-express $F(a,z,h, \dot{h})$ as $\hat{F} = (a,z,t)$

Comment: @Anaedonist Question updated and example included. It would be great if you could please be of help thanks harmut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
$$G(z,L+x)=G(z,L)+G_{.2}(z,L)x +{1\over2!}G_{.22}(z,L)x^2+{1\over3!}G_{.222}(z,L)x^3+\ldots\ .$$
In our case $x=A\sin t$. As $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^k t\>dt=0$ when $k$ is odd, and $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 t\>dt=\pi$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^4 t\>dt={3\pi\over4}$ we obtain
$${1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}G(z,L+A\sin t)\>dt=G(z,L)+{A^2 G_{.22}(z,L)\over4}+{A^4 G_{.2222}(z,L)\over64}+\ldots$$